# Scope confusion regarding session beans, proxies, and singletons in a Spring 3 managed JSF app

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, javabeans, scopes

This seems like it's basic Spring 101 stuff, but I can't seem to find the *correct* way to do this.  The situation is as follows; in my web app there is a single entry point which is a controller that handles users coming from an outside system.  The transfer is just a `POST` request with a bunch of associated information pertaining to that user. Apon entry, I need to create a new User bean and load it with that users information.  Additionally, when the user hits a view which triggers some service, I need for that service to be able to access the appropriate User bean instance.

The first way to do this that came to mind was to have a UserManager service which would create a new instance of User, fill it w/ data, and then register it in the Spring container with the username as the bean name.  Then when a service is invoked, the service would do something like `Factory.getBean(username)` to find the appropriate `User` instance.  The problem I see here is that I'm losing the link between the user & which `User` bean belongs to them.  Additionally, I'd like to avoid having the user carry the bean around in the session if at all possible.  Is this where I am supposed to be using Spring AOP & proxies?

What is the typical Spring pattern for solving this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is now many weeks later (since asking this question), and consequently my knowledge level has been expanding exponentially, so I figured I might as well answer my question for anyone who might find it helpful (not to mention the question wasn't very clear to begin with).

The basic answer is: use proxies.  Since a singleton is only instantiate 1 time, you cant inject another class which has a shorter lifespan, eg. session scope. For those requiring more information, checkout stateful vs stateless beans.  More or less what I ended up doing is this... the services contain STATELESS code for manipulating data (think verbs; RegisterUserSvc, AddPartSvc, etc).  The data which these services manipulate is stateful.  For instance, each user has a own copy of their own data object, lets say TodoListBean, which is in a different state for each user.

So how does a service, AddTodoItemService for instance, manipulate this data? This is where the proxy comes into play.  When instantiated, the AddTodoItemService gets injected with a proxy for the TodoListBean, instead of the actual object.  That way when the service needs to access the TodoListBean the container will serve up the a TodoListBean out of the current users session, and therefore the service will be operating on the correct bean (based on which user invoked the service), instead of doing something silly like having numerous copies of the service included in each users session scope.